# Kocaso M1400 ADB / USB drivers installation on Windows

Tags: usb, android, tablet

I'm having trouble installing the Kocaso M1400 USB / ADB drivers on Windows 8. The vendor doesn't seem to provide them and the generic google drivers don't seem to work. The device is powered by a Rockchip RK3066 chipset. Does anyone know where to find the appropriate driver? Is this a driver signing issue?

Cheers,

E.

Comment: You should be able to use 64-bit Windows 7 drivers, if those are not offered, then you are likely simply out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found here: 
http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/rockchip-rk3066-tablets/59601-how-root-tablet-rockchip-rk30xx-cpu.html

The program Moborobo installs working rockship ADB drivers